# Playwright "setup" project not executing before dependent projects

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, playwright-typescript

I'm trying to add a setup project to Playwright like the [Auth documentations](https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#basic-shared-account-in-all-tests) recommends:

> Create a new setup project in the config and declare it as a dependency for all your testing projects. This project will always run and authenticate before all the tests. All testing projects should use the authenticated state as storageState.

The problem is that it doesn't recognize the `auth.setup.ts` file or isn't running that test. I used this config:

```
 export default defineConfig({
   projects: [ 
    { name: "setup", testMatch: /.*\.setup\.ts/ },
    {
      testDir: "../.",
      name: "CI",
      use: {
        baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
        browserName: "chromium",
        headless: true,
        storageState: "playwright/.auth/user.json",   
      },
     },
   ],
   dependencies: ["setup"],
   globalTeardown: "./global-teardown",
   globalSetup: "./global-setup",
 });
```

I tried to put the file in different directories, change the regex, remove the globalSetup, and put the `dependencies` property inside the `use` object.
Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dependencies` property should be included in a project definition. In your example, `CI` depends on `setup` and should look as follows.

```js
export default defineConfig({
  projects: [ 
    { name: "setup", testMatch: /.*\.setup\.ts/ },
    {
      testDir: "../.",
      name: "CI",
      // this project depends on `setup`
      dependencies: ["setup"],
      use: {
        baseURL: "http://localhost:5000",
        browserName: "chromium",
        headless: true,
        storageState: "playwright/.auth/user.json",   
      },
    },
  ],
});
```